# JMeter: Login flow involving URL redirection not working

Tags: redirect, cookies, jmeter

I am issuing a https POST request with valid credentials for a log in flow and it involves sending few parameters and request headers. I have compared POST data and Request Headers between Jmeter and Firefox (using Firebug) but I have not found any differences except for cookies not being sent through jmeter in Request headers as I have already included the Cookie manager in the test plan.

Login url(status code 302) from firefox redirects me to home page url(status code 200).Now the problem is that Jmeter script is redirecting me to same resource url as login page as if I am not sending valid credentials or request headers. 
I have searched a lot for root cause but can't seem to figure out what could be the problem. Any insights/suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Can u provide sample of your jmeter script?

Comment: Did you check "Follow Redirects" option in HTTP Request details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> except for cookies not being sent through jmeter in Request headers

That might explain everything. In order to send cookies you need to **get** cookies somewhere. Real user **opens** login page prior to typing credentials and clicking "login" or "submit" or whatever button.

Design your test plan as follows:

```
- Config Elements (HTTP Cookie Manager, HTTP Request Defaults, User Defined Variables, etc)
- HTTP Request (GET login page)
    - Post Processors and Assertions if needed
- HTTP Request (POST credentials)
```

See [How To Use JMeter For Login Authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication) article for comprehensive instructions.

A couple of "personal" recommendations:

1. It's better to record your test scenario skeleton rather than creating it manually as errare humanum est. References:

   - [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (was: HTTP Proxy Server )](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
   - [Apache JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
2. I don't trust neither JMeter nor Firebug hence using [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) to compare requests originating from the real browser and JMeter

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I did design my test plan as you described and I noticed that session id was being passed in Cookie Data whenever I had HTTP Cookie Manager enabled. But my login url redirects me to the same page as if my session was not active anymore. So I tried passing that session id in header request explicitly as a Cookie and then it worked (login url redirected to actual home page this time). Any idea what is going on here? I am trying to further investigate this and also look into Wireshark meanwhile. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: So I found the problem - It had nothing to do with Cookies or anything. Apparently one of the parameters passed in the http request was not required anymore which was however was required until last month. And weirdly enough, I still see this parameter being still passed in the request when initiated from a browser. However removing that parameter worked for me!